# What is the area of the shaded part in square centimeter

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The circle is inscribed in a square with sides 8 cm. What is the area of the shaded part in square centimeters? Express your answer in terms of $\pi$

[image]

A nice geometry problem, It's just for sharing a new ideas, thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

Notice, radius of inscribed circle $$=\frac{\text{side of square}}{2}=\frac{8}{2}=4\ cm$$
Area of shaded part $$=\text{(area of semi-circle with radius}\ 4 \ cm)-\text{(area of isosceles triangle)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\pi (4)^2-\frac{1}{2}(2)(8)$$$$=8\pi-8=8(\pi-1)\approx 17.13274123 \ cm^2$$ $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{Area of shaded portion}=8(\pi-1)\approx 17.13274123\ cm^2}}$$

Comment: Assuming that the triangles kiss at the midpoint of the line, sure.

Comment: Isn´t $r=8$ ?...

Comment: Kindly, notice $\text{side of square}=\text{diameter of circle}=8\ cm$ $$r=4\ cm$$

Comment: I see after I have read the text. But from the picture it looks like that $r=8$ On the other hand it can be interpretated as $r=4$

Comment: Nice solution :)